# Notify Java application of changes in Apache Derby database

Tags: java, database, apache, jdbc

I have a Java application that can save and retrieve data from an Apache Derby database using JDBC. I would like to update the view of every user when changes are made in the database.

I tried using a for-loop that polls the database every few seconds, but that uses loads of processor time as expected. I've also heard about TimeTask and ScheduledExecutorService. I'm not sure how they work but i imagine they are a better alternative to the for-loop. However they would also have to check the database, which i find less ideal than having the database notify of changes.

I've read about database Triggers, which i think might be the best solution? However, all the examples i find for apache derby only seem to trigger other changes in the database and not the Java application.

Is it possible to use a trigger to execute a method in the Java application? If so, how? or perhaps there is another approach to solving the problem that I don't know of?

Comment: How is the database being updated?

Comment: I have Java methods that use a PreparedStatement to change the database

Comment: So why not trigger whatever notification mechanism you're using off of the Java method that updates the DB?

Comment: I have no communication between the clients other than the database. How could i change the view of one client from another client?

Comment: ... What kind of app is it? Web? Desktop? Mobile? How are you running Derby?

Comment: It's a desktop app. For now i'm just running Derby through NetBeans, I'm not quite sure how i will run it in the end, but i suppose that's a separate question

Comment: Not really. If you're running an embedded Derby then you have little hope of this working. You need to be running Derby as a server, and even then, I'm not sure it supports doing anything other than DB operations--and even if it did more, it would likely be something JMS-ish which would still require something to run JMS. You might want to consider putting the DB behind a REST service that can handle notifications, or switching DBs.